# Why does this ajax script copied selectbox?

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, http-post

I just trying city-state select. I think this code blocks print the posting data to screen.. but it copies selectbox and then prints the selectbox to screen. Isn't it weird?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ilce').change(function(){
    var ilceid = $('#ilce').val();



     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ilce/ajax',
      data: 'ilceid'+ilceid,
      success: function(sonuc){
        $('#ilce').css('background-color','#efefef');
        $('#semt').html(sonuc);
      }


     });

  });
});
```

html is:

```
<?php echo  form_open('ilce/index')?>
<select id="ilce" name="ilce">
<option value="">Select Town</option>
<?php foreach ($ilce as $x):?>
<option value="<?php echo $x['id']?>"><?php echo $x['ad']?></option>
<?php endforeach?>
</select>
<p id="semt"></p>
```

and, ilce/ajax controller which must print the post data???

```
<?php

class Ilce extends CI_Controller{

        public function ajax()
        {
                print_r($_POST);

        }


} //end of controller
```

As I said, this code must be print post data in `<p id="semt"></p>` right?

But this code just  copies `<select>` and after `.change()` immediately paste to screen then there becomes 2 selectboxes.

Comment: Have you tried debbuing your code with firebug or google chrome developer tools? Use this tools and check the xhr requests under network tab

Comment: @FabioAntunes i'm trying right now i'm loking xhr requests and a lot of things there, what must i seek?

Comment: just change the value of the select to fire the ajax post request, then see in that request wich data was sent and what was the response

Comment: @FabioAntunes i see this when i change select "Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
ilceid463 
Source"   this is copy from POST tab in the XHR tab.
ilceid463 "

Comment: you're using chrome or firefox with firebug?

Comment: i'm using firebug with firefox...

Comment: If you click on one of the ajax post requests e have 4 options headers, post, response. See the response tab

Comment: @FabioAntunes http://pastie.org/6607072 this is the response...